# Is it safe to use RefCell in a data structure accessed with some coarse grained lock?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, concurrency, traits, rust-tokio

I'm writing some tokio async code. I have a multi-index data structure keeping users where I want to guard them with a coarse-grained lock (contrary to per-object lock). I have something like this:

```rust
use tokio::sync::RwLock;

struct User {
  id: u64,
  name: String,
}

// This class is not thread-safe.
struct UserDb {
  by_id: HashMap<u64, Arc<RefCell<User>>>,
  by_name: HashMap<String, Arc<RefCell<User>>>,
}

impl UserDb {
  pub fn add_user(&mut self, name: String) -> Result<(), Error> {
    // ...
  }
}

// This class is thread-safe.
struct AsyncDb {
  users: RwLock<UserDb>,
}

impl AsyncDb {
  pub async fn add_user(&self, name: String) -> Result<(), Error> {
    self.users.write().await.add_user(name)
  }
}

// QUESTION: Are these safe?
unsafe impl Send for AsyncDb {}
unsafe impl Sync for AsyncDb {}
```

Without `Send` and `Sync` traits at the end, the compiler complains `RefCell<User>` isn't `Send` and `Sync` (reasonably so), and hence not safe to access/modify through `AsyncDb::add_user`.

My solution was to implement `Send` and `Sync` for the data structure since there is a coarse grained lock in `AsyncDb` around `UserDb`, which contains said `RefCell`s.

Is this a correct solution? Does it violate any invariants? Is there a better way to handle this?

Note: Rust beginner here. I likely have many conceptual gaps, so please call it out if things don't make sense.

Comment: I'd probably just store the users in a `Vec<User>` and have 2 `HashMap<K, usize>` to avoid the need for `Arc` and `RefCell` alltogether. That struct would implement `Send` and `Sync` automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly *not* sound unless you *only* take write locks even when reading from users.

The `RefCell::borrow*()` functions are not thread-safe because they do not maintain the internal refcount atomically.  This means using `borrow()` to read from a `RefCell<User>` when only guarded by a read lock is unsound.

If you are already sold on this particular design, I would strongly recommend replacing your `RwLock` with a `Mutex`, as read locks will be almost completely useless.

Replacing `RwLock` with `Mutex` will make your type automatically implement `Sync` but it still won't implement `Send`.  If you keep your `unsafe impl Send` in this case then you need to be very careful with the `Arc`s.  You must never:

- Return an `Arc<RefCell<User>>` or a reference to one either directly or embedded in another value as that will allow the caller to clone their own `Arc` that they can use to manipulate the `RefCell` without holding a lock.
- Send an `Arc<RefCell<User>>` or reference to one to another thread/task via `thread::spawn()`, `tokio::spawn()`, `tokio::spawn_blocking()`, sending one on a channel, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I have a better understanding why I'd better use Mutex/RWLock instead of RefCell there. For future reference, I also tried to reprod the problem in playground, but I couldn't. The actual error I got in my messy local code was "future created by async block is not `Send` help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `RefCell<User>`".

Comment: With `Mutex` you don't need the `unsafe impl`s, since `RefCell` is `Send` (and BTW, you just found a use-case for `Arc<RefCell>`!)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I thought I found a soundness hole in safe Rust based on that, but then figured out that `Arc<RefCell>` isn't `Send` -- which makes the bit in my answer about not exposing the `Arc`s incorrect. You actually _can_ expose the `Arc`s and the caller could clone them, but wouldn't be able to send them to other threads anyway.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Actually, wait... there still may be a problem. I'm going to write up a playground.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Nope, nevermind. `Mutex<T>` is only `Send` when `T` is, which means `Mutex<Arc<RefCell>>` is not `Send` -- so the `unsafe impl Send` would be necessary, and if that's done then my warnings about exposing the `Arc`s are valid.

Answer (score 2):

This structure is not safe. `RefCell` cannot be used on two threads simultaneously (i.e. it doesn't implement `Sync`) and your structure is not protecting against that.

Since you use a `RwLock`, that means you can give multiple readers immutable access to the value from different threads, which is not allowed. But even if you changed it to a `Mutex` such that it is exclusive, your `Arc` allows ownership to escape the guard of the mutex and preserve immutable access in another thread regardless.

That being said, implementing `Send` and `Sync` is *probably* valid if you ensure that no `Arc`s escape the `Mutex`'s protection. Though if you do that, you could probably even downgrade them to `Rc`s instead. And yes, it would have to be `Mutex` and not `RwLock` because, again, you can't access a `RefCell` from multiple threads at the same time, even immutably.

Comment: **And yes, it would have to be Mutex and not RwLock because, again, you can't access a RefCell from multiple threads at the same time, even immutably.** That's very helpful. Thanks. (Marking cdhowie's reply as answer as it also has some context around tokio.)